# Java Mockito: How to prepare different answers

Tags: java, mockito

```
int calledCnt = 0;
doAnswer(i -> {
    if (calledCnt == 0) {
        calledCnt += 1;
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("test");
    }
    return false;
}).when(myClass.someFunction(any()));
```

I want to stub a call where if it was called initially throw an exception but any subsequent calls will return false;

the above call complains `"Variables used in lambda should be final or effectively final"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make `calledCnt` something mutable (e.g. an `int[]` with a single element, or an `AtomicInteger`), or declare the answer as an anonymous class, so you can add a member variable:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
  int calledCnt = 0;

  @Object public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    if (calledCnt == 0) {
      calledCnt += 1;
      throw new InternalServerErrorException("test");
    }
    return false;
  }
}).when(...);
```

(Actually, it doesn't have to be an anonymous class, it can be any sort of class. It's simply convenient to use an anonymous class, because it keeps everything localized to where it will be used.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether `myClass` is the thing you're testing, or a dependency, I would recommend wholly or partially mocking `myClass` (i.e. at least the `someFunction()` call). Using `then...()` methods you can specify a *series* of items to return, e.g.:

```
when(myMockedClass.someFunction(any()))
    .thenThrow(new InternalServerErrorException("test"))
    .thenReturn(false);
```

The *first* call will throw an exception, and the second call *and all subsequent calls* will return false.